# SQL help - select table with the greatest number of related rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three database tables: `routes`, `trips`, and `stoptimes` that contain transit information.  They're related with foreign keys as follows:

```
         routes -> ROUTE_ID -> trips -> TRIP_ID -> stoptimes
```

i.e. there are some routes, lots of trips per route, and even more stoptimes per trip.

For each route in the table I'd like to select the trip that has the greatest number of stoptimes.

Furthermore, each route has an enum (INT) `direction_id` too and I'd like to select the trip with the most stoptimes for each direction, for each route.

This is all for some data pre-processing, the idea is that these selected trips will have a flag set on them so that they can be easily recalled in future.

Is it possible to achieve this in SQL?

---

**EDIT:**

More info as requested.  Here is a sample SELECT query / results table:

```
select t.route_id, t.direction_id, t.trip_id, NumStops, t.isPrototypical
from trips t join
     (select st.trip_id, count(*) as NumStops
      from stoptimes st
      group by st.trip_id
     ) st
     on st.trip_id = t.trip_id;
```

Results:

[image: sample sql results table]

In the example above, I want a SQL statement that would select trips 2 and 10, since these have the (equal-)greatest NumStops in each direction.  Even better if, rather than `SELECTING` the SQL statement could `UPDATE` the column `isPrototypical` to `TRUE` for those particular rows.

Bear in mind: in the production DB there will be more than one `route_id` and an arbitrary number of `direction_id`s on each trip.  The statement needs to do its magic for each direction, and per route.

---

**Final Answer**

A correct, well-performing solution was provided by Gordon Linoff, below, and I thought I would also post the modified version of his code that I used to solve the problem.

Here's the SQL that selects and updates the trips with the most stops, per route, per direction, while only picking one trip in the event of a tie:

```
update trips t join  ( select substring_index(group_concat(t.trip_id order by NumStops desc), ',', 1) as prototripid from trips t join
     (select st.trip_id, count(*) as NumStops
      from stoptimes st
      group by st.trip_id
     ) st
     on st.trip_id = t.trip_id group by t.route_id, t.direction_id ) t2 on t2.prototripid = t.trip_id set isPrototypical = 1 ;
```

I believe that this may be MySQL-specific.

Comment: It would be helpful to have sample data and desired output, perhaps a Fiddle (SQLFiddle.Com) would be nice?  Not sure I understand how direction_id plays into things at the moment.

Comment: What should be done on ties? (two or more trips with same number of stoptimes)

Comment: @ypercube In the event of a tie, either trip may be selected, but not both.

Comment: @sgeddes Question updated with sample data as requested - hope this helps.

Comment: @CarlosP -- why 7 and 10?  4, 5 and 7 all have the highest for direction_id = 1?

Comment: @sgeddes Yep sorry you're right.  Any of those rows would also do, as long as they're equal to the maximum value.  Will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @CarlosP -- posted an answer which should help.  Might be an easier solution, but this should work.

Comment: @sgeddes Your answer is nearly correct, but multiple rows are updated per direction, whereas I only want one row.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a trick in MySQL, involving group concatenation.

Here is the query:

```
select t.route_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(t.trip_id order by NumStops desc), ',', 1),
       max(NumStops) as Length
from trips t join
     (select st.trip_id, count(*) as NumStops
      from stoptimes st
      group by st.trip_id
     ) st
     on st.trip_id = t.trip_id
group by t.route_id;
```

(You don't need the `routes` table unless you need the name of the route.)

The subquery counts the number of stops on each trip.  This is then aggregated by `route_id`.

Normally, `group_concat()` would be used to put all the trips in a comma-delimited string.  Here it does that, with the caveat that they are ordered by the number of stops with the longest first.  The function `substring_index()` then takes the first value.

This converts the `trip_id` to a string.  You might want to convert it back to whatever data type it started out as.

The following gets the best for each direction:

```
select t.route_id, t.direction_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(t.trip_id order by NumStops desc), ',', 1),
       max(NumStops) as Length
from trips t join
     (select st.trip_id, count(*) as NumStops
      from stoptimes st
      group by st.trip_id
     ) st
     on st.trip_id = t.trip_id
group by t.route_id, t.direction_id;
```

Because the direction is stored a the *trip* level, it doesn't interfere with the counting of stops on a trip (that is, it doesn't seem to be needed in the `st` subquery.

Comment: This is nice, and was helpful, but it ignores the `direction_id` of the trips.  I've used part of your SELECT statement to add some sample data to the question to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @CarlosP . . . The direction is at the trip level, so the query in your question seems to handle it.  For this query, you just need to add it to the outermost select and `group by` clause to get the best id for each direction.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that was the missing piece of the puzzle.  Neat trick!  Any idea why, performance-wise, it takes a huge hit when I wrap the whole thing with `SELECT * from trips where trip_id in (`  ?   (having removed the other columns from your select so only trip_id remains)   (http://pastebin.com/8iB1Tf8y)

Comment: @CarlosP . . . Yes, you are using an older version of MySQL where the `in` is really poorly implemented.  Sometimes, you can fix this using `exists (select . . .)` with a correlated `where` clause.

Comment: I'm using 5.6.11 which is pretty recent, is that affected?  For me, the final task to lay this one to rest is to update these trips now by setting `isPrototypical` to 1   Helpful if you have any links to workarounds such as the one you suggest.

Comment: OK, solved - the solution to fix performance was to do a `JOIN` on `trips` and the 2nd `SELECT` statement above. This can be easily modified to an UPDATE statement which I might post as an edit to my original question to illustrate the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you join all the tables together correctly, you'll get one row for each stop time, so a `COUNT(*)` will give you the total stops.

As for the count by direction, I'll assume the direction values are `1, 2, 3, ...`. I can't tell which table `direction_id` is in so I've left it unaliased in the query:

```
SELECT routes.Route_ID
   COUNT(*) AS TotalStops,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN direction_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Direction1Stops,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN direction_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Direction2Stops,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN direction_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Direction3Stops,
   ... and the remaining direction_id values
FROM routes
INNER JOIN trips ON routes.Route_ID = trips.Route_ID
INNER JOIN stoptimes on trips.Trip_ID = stoptimes.Trip_ID
GROUP BY routes.Route_ID
```

Comment: This returns the total count of the stops per direction, but it doesn't do anything with it - I want to select and update the rows with the highest count, per direction, per group.  Also, there is an arbitrary number of direction_ids per trip so I can't hard code those into the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, the concept is to join the results on themselves, using `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.  This wouldn't look so bad if MySQL supported Common Table Expressions:

```
update trips t
  join (
    select t.route_id, t.direction_id, t.trip_id, NumStops, t.isPrototypical
    from trips t join
         (select st.trip_id, count(*) as NumStops
          from stoptimes st
          group by st.trip_id
         ) st
         on st.trip_id = t.trip_id
    ) t2 on t.trip_id = t2.trip_id
  join (
    select max(numstops) maxnumstops, route_id, direction_id
    from (
      select t.route_id, t.direction_id, t.trip_id, NumStops, t.isPrototypical
      from trips t join
         (select st.trip_id, count(*) as NumStops
          from stoptimes st
          group by st.trip_id
         ) st
         on st.trip_id = t.trip_id
      ) t
    group by route_id, direction_id
    ) t3 on t2.numstops = t3.maxnumstops and t2.route_id = t3.route_id and t2.direction_id = t3.direction_id
set t.isPrototypical = 1;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/675c0/1)

Comment: This very nearly works, but when two trips have the same number of stops, both are flagged as `isPrototypical` rather than just one of them.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @CarlosP -- you only want to update one of them?  Which one?  Any of them?  That was what I was asking in my comment earlier :D

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I only want to update one row per direction, I don't mind which one.  The first one located is fine.  How would I do that?